# Maven 3 regression: Profile dependencies lost?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I observed a change behavior between Maven 2 and Maven 3. Is this a bug or a feature? I couldn't find anything in the [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html)

I use two different profiles to add dependencies for different environment in a multi-module project.

parent-pom:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>portal</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

The common-pom has the profile in it:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>   
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>   
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.14</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles> 
</project>
```

The portal-pom has only the common dependency and should include the transitive dependency from the common module:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>portal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>   
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Building this project (from the parent) via Maven2 `mvn -P production package` results in a WAR which includes the transitive dependency. (I used those simple dependencies for easy reproduction)
Executing via Maven3, I get only the common.jar in the WAR, but not the transitive dependency.

Is this a desired behavior?

To make things even "interesting": If one of the profiles is activated by default (explicit in the common-pom as the activation is not derived from the parent to the child modules) these transitive dependencies are always add to the portal.
But filtering or property-setting via profiles works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [comment](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1388?focusedCommentId=182825&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-182825) solves it the one way:

> the situation described above does work when profile activation using properties is used

With property activation (and not via -P) it works in Maven2 and 3

But the real solution was "caused" by the release plugin:
The profile must be submitted to release-plugin via
`-Darguments=-Pproduction`

Comment: Glad you included the comment essence, as the link seems to have rotted.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but your use case looks similar to [this open](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1388) maven bug.  Interestingly, according to the bug details, it happens on earlier maven versions as well.